# How to change sound of iOS remote notifications without changing push payload

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile-development

I want to change the sound of remote notifications in iOS. But I do not want to send the sound name in push payload. I want to set it from the device itself.
This is possible in Android.
But no idea how to do it in iOS.

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: The only way I can think of is to push a silent notification that would then trigger a local notification with your desired sound.

Comment: @meaning-matters, the op does *not* want to put the `sound` key in their payload

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 10 it is possible via [UNNotificationServiceExtension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension).

You would need to send `mutable-content` flag as 1 in your payload. This will trigger your notification service extension to intercept notification before showing the same to the user. 
You can modify content of this notification in extension's method:

```
func didReceive(UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler: (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)
```

For further reference, [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-10-notification-service-extensions--cms-27550) to a good introductory tutorial.